# How do Unitarian see the Problem of sharing YHWHs Honor with the Son? Isaiah 48:11 and John 5:23

Tags: trinity, textual-discrepancies, unitarianism, biblical-unitarian

In Isaiah 48:11 we see that the Father YHWH does not share his Glory/Honor with anybody.

> For mine own sake, even for mine own sake, will I do it: for how should my name be polluted? and I will not give my glory unto another. (Isa 48:11)

And also ...

> I am the LORD: that is my name: and my glory will I not give to another, neither my praise to graven images. (Isa 42:8)

But Yeshua claims, that he shall be honored the same way as the father.

> That all men should honour the Son, even as they honour the Father. He that honoureth not the Son honoureth not the Father which hath sent him. (John 5:23)

For me it may be a contradiction. How do Unitarians or Arians see this contradiction? The Father YHWH says, he shares his honor with nobody, but the Son demands the same honor as the father.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142558/discussion-on-question-by-biblical-monotheist-how-do-unitarian-see-the-problem-o); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

John's verse can essentially be read as it is:

All men should honour the Son-of-God (Messiah), even as they honour the Father, because, if someone who does not honour whom God has sent, he disrespects God, His Word, His Teachings.

see also John 7:16-18

> “My teaching is not My own,” Jesus replied. “It comes from Him who sent Me. If anyone desires to do His will, he will know whether My teaching is from God or whether I speak on My own. He who speaks on his own authority seeks his own glory, but He who seeks the glory of the One who sent Him is a man of truth; in Him there is no falsehood.

(Berean Standard)

Comment: Where is the connection to Isaiah?